# Determine If Table Has Consecutive Primary ID Auto Increment Values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there a way to determine whether a table, a very large table possibly, has contiguous / consecutive auto increment primary key IDs? Is there a SQL query way to determine this? Suppose someone deletes some rows randomly from a very large table. I need to know that this has happened.

```
e.g. 
table XYZ
id
1
2
3
4

table abc
1
2
4 <--- non contiguous, skipped 3
5
```

Curious about data integrity. I want a SQL query methodology way in order to just keep things simple and not have to write a PHP script to run against the database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could compare these two values:

```
SELECT (MAX(ID) - MIN(ID)) + 1, -- e.g. ID 2 - ID 1 = 1 (+1) = 2 rows
       COUNT(ID)
FROM Table
```

If the table is still contiguous they will be the same.

Comment: I am not sure that it is necessary to work out the difference of MIN(id) and MAX(id). Comparing `MAX(ID)` to `COUNT()` should be enough to work out if it is or not. eg `SELECT (MAX(id) - COUNT(*)) FROM table` where 0 means contiguous and > 1 is the number records missing.

Comment: @Treffynnon: Assuming the table `ID` column starts with 0 or positive numbers.  If for some reason it begins negative - which it can - then you do actually have to compare the difference.

Answer (score 4):

How about this: count the number of rows, subtract the lowest ID from the highest, and if the two numbers match then the IDs are contiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Use a self join

```
SELECT *
FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID + 1
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

If there are no gaps, this will return only one row, for the last element in the table.  You could even eliminate that row from the results set if you want to be clever, but this should give you the idea.

This technique is particularly useful if you want to do more work with the gaps.  If not, the counting techniques others suggested are simpler.

Comment: If you need to actually know the start and end of each island you should be able to do this with a single scan of the table and no joins if you use user variables. Similar to the greatest-n-per-group approach.

Comment: Similar technique to here http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/